# Checkbox tab index not working when set to hidden with custom design

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm using a checkbox and adding a custom design to it using CSS

```
label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em; }

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  padding: 0.5em;
 }

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none; 
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  padding-left: 1.5em; 
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 4px;
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2713"; /* "✓" */ 
}
```

But the problem is that when navigating the form with the keyboard with the tab key the check box is ignored. How can I include it in the flow of navigation?

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/vogoripi/1/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I changed it from display: none; to opacity: 0; and it works fine here is the new edited code

http://jsbin.com/yuxizazo/1

Comment: another option for anyone else reading this, would be to put a negative margin-right on the checkbox so that a custom checkbox to the right of the original checkbox overlaps it

Comment: @Adam Marshall: I tried this, but didn't fix the height issue. Setting position: absolute worked for me.

Comment: Note that in Apple's Safari you need to enable the tabindex functionality in the *Advanced* panel of the browser settings first. It took me a while to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have "display:none;" set on the actual checkbox.

If you remove that it works fine:
http://jsbin.com/vogoripi/2

If you do want to use another method for styling checkboxes while keeping this functionality you should maybe look at a plugin like:
http://uniformjs.com/

I would suggest leaving them as is and just leaving the standard checkbox, as you may run in to problems further down the line.

Comment: I changed it from display: none; to opacity: 0; and it works fine  here is the new edited code http://jsbin.com/yuxizazo/1/