# HTML / CSS hide checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, hide

How can I hide a checkbox using HTML / CSS?

Let's say I have

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
         Col A
        </th>
         <th>
         Col B
         </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"> Some stuff </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> Some Other stuff </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The name and the values of the checkbox are not constant. I know there's some way with jquery but is there a way to hide it with pure CSS or HTML?

Comment: The answers below all work, the real question is why would you want to?  If you're trying to pass data to a form, just use <input type="hidden" name="V" value="B" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide the checkbox (or any HTML item with the class of "hidden") from display. The checkbox still exists in HTML and can be enabled/disabled with Javascript or by visitors with developer tools.

Comment: The checkbox might also not be submitted correctly.

Comment: Keep in mind that setting `display: none` also hides the checkbox in screen readers and disables the default tab focus.

Answer (score 22):

Please keep in mind that setting the *display* property to *none*, makes the element inaccessible using tabs (see: [Checkbox tab index not working when set to hidden with custom design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042212/checkbox-tab-index-not-working-when-set-to-hidden-with-custom-design)). If you case about accessibility, you can use:

```
input[type=checkbox].hidden{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple enough!

```
input[type=checkbox].hidden{
   display:none;
}
```

Or if you want to be crazy and use inline styles (best to avoid):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="V" value="B" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer. However, I have multiple checkboxes inside my table with different names and values so I can't therefore rely on this.

Comment: @Wistar - I've amended, not you can use CSS to target an element on `id` `class` decendancy or any attribute

Comment: Thats odd, it is effectively the same as the OPs accepted answer above :S its likely you may have a different issue?

Comment: Crazy and use inline styles LOL? If I know hiding the box is forever I only use inline styling.

Answer (score -1):

you have class `hidden` added to that checkbox.

```
input[type=checkbox].hidden {
   display:none;
}
```

or just

```
.hidden {
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

this will work.