# button by default hide then show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

it is showing the checkboxes, but by default i want it to hide but after click show

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#ElectronicsChk").toggle(1000);
        $("#SoftwareChk").toggle(1000);
        $("#Dontknow").toggle(1000);
        $("p").toggle(1000);
    });
});
</script>
<style>
div.electro{
     background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn1">Electronics</button>
<button id="btn2">Homeapplainces</button>
<button id="btn3">Downloadable</button>


<div class="electro">
<input type="checkbox" id="ElectronicsChk">
    <p>Hardware Problems</p></input>
    <input type="checkbox" id="SoftwareChk">
    <p>Software Problems</p></input>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Dontknow">
    <p>I dont Know</p></input>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

plz help i am a newbie so plz do explain after submitting your code,... Sorry and i'll be very thankfull for the help... waiting for an early response thank you...

Comment: `$.toggle()` just toggles the display property, so you can set the elements to `display: none` initially using CSS, then let `$.toggle()` handle the toggling after that. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRgoyy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML / CSS hide checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683136/html-css-hide-checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the checkboxes and p initially, you can simply use CSS:

```
div.electro > * {
    display:none;
}
```

That said, it seems you could simplify your code by hiding and showing the div container instead of each individual child element:

CSS:

```
div.electro {
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $(".electro").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

This is much better because it follows the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and is more flexible, for example if you adding some new elements to the container like some helper text, you don't need to update the JavaScript logic.

Comment: @xsami your link only comment makes no sense. Care to explain?

Comment: thank you so much sir also the animation is working thanks:)

Comment: @MrCode The thing is that you should not response duplicated questions. He is only asking about how to hide an element

Comment: @xsami adding a hidden class to all child elements superfluous and a poor solution at best.